Reading values bassed on environment standard logic apps
I am trying to read variable values based on environment in workflow.json. I have a value configured in App settings of standard logic app which is env and this variable will have a value dev, stag or prod based on environments. I need to read the below variable values based on environments and right now I am using @{variables('_Uri')[@appsettings('env')]['G1']} to do that. For some reason, this is not working. I am new to logic apps and trying to learn, would need help with this. Thank you!
    "inputs": {
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "_Uri",
                "type": "object",
                "value": {
                    "dev": {
                        "G1": "https://google.com",
                        "G2": "https://google1.com",
                        "G3": "https://google2.com",
                        "G4": "https://google3.com",
                        "G5": "https://google4.com",
                        "G6": "https://google5.com",
                        "G7": "https://google6.com",
                        "G8": "https://google7.com"
                    },
                    "stag": {
                        "G1": "https://google.com",
                        "G2": "https://google1.com",
                        "G3": "https://google2.com",
                        "G4": "https://google3.com",
                        "G5": "https://google4.com",
                        "G6": "https://google5.com",
                        "G7": "https://google6.com",
                        "G8": "https://google7.com"
                    },
                    "prod": {
                        "G1": "https://google.com",
                        "G2": "https://google1.com",
                        "G3": "https://google2.com",
                        "G4": "https://google3.com",
                        "G5": "https://google4.com",
                        "G6": "https://google5.com",
                        "G7": "https://google6.com",
                        "G8": "https://google7.com"
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}```


I am able to fetch the values from app settings in standard logic app using below workflow.
Use @{variables('_Uri')[appsetting('env')]['G1']} expression.

Code -
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('_Uri')[appsetting('env')]['G1']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Set_variable": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "_Uri",
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Set_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "name": "_Uri",
                    "value": {
                        "dev": {
                            "G1": "https://google.com",
                            "G2": "https://google1.com",
                            "G3": "https://google2.com",
                            "G4": "https://google3.com",
                            "G5": "https://google4.com",
                            "G6": "https://google5.com",
                            "G7": "https://google6.com",
                            "G8": "https://google7.com"
                        },
                        "prod": {
                            "G1": "https://google.com",
                            "G2": "https://google1.com",
                            "G3": "https://google2.com",
                            "G4": "https://google3.com",
                            "G5": "https://google4.com",
                            "G6": "https://google5.com",
                            "G7": "https://google6.com",
                            "G8": "https://google7.com"
                        },
                        "stag": {
                            "G1": "https://google.com",
                            "G2": "https://google1.com",
                            "G3": "https://google2.com",
                            "G4": "https://google3.com",
                            "G5": "https://google4.com",
                            "G6": "https://google5.com",
                            "G7": "https://google6.com",
                            "G8": "https://google7.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "SetVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}

Output -

